# get common xpath ancestor node?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [finding common ancestor from a group of xpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485211/finding-common-ancestor-from-a-group-of-xpath)

im using nokogiri.

i need to get the common xpath ancestor of group of elements.

Answer (score 3):

There we go

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

class Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet
  def common_ancestor
    return nil if empty?
    ancestors = self.collect{ |e| e.ancestors.to_a.reverse }
    common = nil
    ancestors.shift.zip(*ancestors) do |nodes|
      break if nodes.uniq.size > 1
      common = nodes.first
    end
    return common
  end
end

doc = Nokogiri::XML(DATA.read)
p doc.css('.leaf').common_ancestor.path


__END__
<html><body><span>
<div><p><h1><i><font class="leaf"/></i></h1></p></div>
<div><div><div><div><table><tr><p><h1 class="leaf"/></p></tr></table></div></div></div></div>
<p><h1><b class="leaf"/></h1></p>
</span></body></html>
```

added it to the `NodeSet` class, so we can call it as a method.