# Generalizing XPaths

Tags: javascript, xml, firefox, machine-learning

I would like seek your help for a problem I am trying to tackle involving XPaths.

I am trying to generalize multiple Xpaths provided by a user to get an XPath that would best 'fit' all the provided examples. This is for a web scraping system I am building.

**Eg:** If the user gives the following xpaths (each pointing to a link in the 'Spotlight' section from the Google News page)

*Good examples:*

```
/html/body/div[@id='page']/div/div[@id='main-wrapper']/div[@id='main']/div/div/div[3] /div[1]/table[@id='main-am2-pane']/tbody/tr/td[@id='rt-col']/div[3]/div[@id='s_en_us:ir']/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/a[@id='MAE4AUgAUABgAmoCdXM']/span

/html/body/div[@id='page']/div/div[@id='main-wrapper']/div[@id='main']/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/table[@id='main-am2-pane']/tbody/tr/td[@id='rt-col']/div[3]/div[@id='s_en_us:ir']/div[2]/div[6]/div[2]/a[@id='MAE4AUgFUABgAmoCdXM']/span

/html/body/div[@id='page']/div/div[@id='main-wrapper']/div[@id='main']/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/table[@id='main-am2-pane']/tbody/tr/td[@id='rt-col']/div[3]/div[@id='s_en_us:ir']/div[2]/div[12]/div[2]/a[@id='MAE4AUgLUABgAmoCdXM']/span
```

*Bad Examples: (pointing to a link in another section)*

```
/html/body/div[@id='page']/div/div[@id='main-wrapper']/div[@id='main']/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/table[@id='main-am2-pane']/tbody/tr/td[@id='lt-col']/div[2]/div[@id='replaceable-section-blended']/div[1]/div[4]/div/h2/a[@id='MAA4AEgFUABgAWoCdXM']/span
```

It should be able to **generalize and produce an xpath expression** that would select all the links in the 'Spotlight' section. (It should be able to throw out the incorrect xpath given)

**Generalized XPath**

```
/html/body/div[@id='page']/div/div[@id='main-wrapper']/div[@id='main']/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/table[@id='main-am2-pane']/tbody/tr/td[@id='rt-col']/div[3]/div[@id='s_en_us:ir']/div[2]/div/div[2]/a[@id='MAE4AUgLUABgAmoCdXM']/span
```

Could you kindly advice me on how to go about it. I was thinking of using the Longest Common Substring strategy but however that would over-generalize if a bad example is given (like the fourth example given) Are there any libraries or any open source software that has been done in this area?

I saw some similar posts ([finding common ancestor from a group of xpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485211/finding-common-ancestor-from-a-group-of-xpath) and [Howto find the first common XPath ancestor in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867464/howto-find-the-first-common-xpath-ancestor-in-javascript)) However they are talking about longest common ancestor.

I am writing it in Javascript as a form of a firefox extension.

Thanks for your time and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is. You haven't defined what "bad" XPath expressions are and what "good" Xpath expressions are. Also, you haven't defined what is to be done if a "bad" expression is entered. Please, edit your question and define carefully and as precisely as possible the problem.

Comment: Hi Dimitre, using the above example, suppose a  user wants to extract all the links from the spotlight section of google news, he can give a few examples of the xpaths that point the 'spotlight' links. suppose he accidentally gave 1 'bad' example - a random xpath to some other content, the system should not fall into the trap and try to generalize it such that it covers the 'bad' xpath.

Comment: @user649851: It looks like you want the innermost almost common ancestor with more descendants from a given node set. When the nodes from the nodeset are from the same document, they have at least one common ancestor: the root element in the worst case. So, if you want the innermost that means you have to compare the deph against that surely common ancestor. Also, because you want the almost common you have to choose wich node from the node set you won't consider. This two process make this task imposible for a single XPath expression, I think.

Comment: @user649851: The "xpath" tag is for well-defined questions and yours isn't. Unless you define what is a "bad" question and what is a "good" question... I think that these are moral concepts and cannot be subject of a precize scientific or engineering discipline. This is definitely *not* an XPath question.

Answer (score 0):

The question here is in Automaton minimization problem. So you have (Xpath1|Xpath2|Xpath3) and you would like to get minimal automaton Xpath4 which match same nodes. THere are also question about minimization with information lose or not, like JPEG. For exact minimization you could google "Algorithms for Minimization of Finite-State Automata".

Ok, the simplest way is finding common subsequence, after converting each Xpath operator to character and run character based substring finder from list of string. So we have for example

adcba, acba, adba --common substring--> aba --general reg exp--> a.*b.*a --convert back to xpath--> ...

You can also try to set something less general in place of .*